Showing that the subring of rational functions defined in the complement of V(G) can be identified with a localization of the polynomial ring
I have been working through Aluffi's Algebra: Chapter 0 and am struggling with Exercise 2.16 in Chapter VII. The exercise is as follows:

Let $K$ be an algebraically closed field and denote the field of rational functions over K by $K(x_1, ... , x_n)$. Every rational function $α =\frac{F}{G}$ (with $G \neq 0$ and $F, G$ relatively prime) may be viewed as defining a function on the open set $\mathbb{A}^n_{K} \backslash \mathcal{V}(G)$; we say that $α$ is ‘defined’ for all points in the complement of the variety $\mathcal{V}(G)$. Let $G ∈ K[x_1, ... , x_n]$ be irreducible. The set of rational functions that are defined in the complement of $\mathcal{V} (G)$ is a subring of $K(x_1, . . . , x_n)$.


Prove that this subring may be identified with the localization of $K[\mathbb{A}^n_K]=K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ at the multiplicative set $\{1, G, G^2, G^3, ... \}$.

The question comes with a hint to use the Nullstellensatz. Here is what I am thinking so far: The localisation is the ring that is initial with regards to the property of being a ring $R$ s.t. there is homomorphism $\phi:K[x_1, ..., x_n] \to R$ and $\phi(x)$ is invertible for all $x \in \{1, G, G^2, G^3, ... \}$. So what I want to show is that the subring of rational functions has this property.
My problem is that I don't know how to deal with the subring of rational functions defined on the complement of $\mathcal{V}(G)$. I know the polynomial $G$ is irreducible, so the ideal $(G)$ is prime, so the algebraic set $\mathcal{V}(G)$ is irreducible, in the sense that it cannot be written as the union of two algebraic proper subsets of $\mathcal{V}(G)$. But my worry is that, for example, there might be a polynomial $f$ in $K[x_1, ..., x_n]$ s.t. $\mathcal{V}(f) \subset \mathcal{V}(G)$ and $f \neq G$, so $f$ is invertible in the subring. If there is such an $f$, would this subring still be initial wrt this property?
Is there a simpler way? Am I confused or am I missing a part of the argument?
Thank you.

Let $g\in k[x_1,\dots,x_n]$, and $R$ be the ring of rational functions that are defined in the on the compliment $U_g=\mathbb A^n_k\smallsetminus V(g)$. I will show that $R$ is naturally isomorphic to the localization of $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]_g$.
Assuming that $g$ is irreducible, we know that $\langle g\rangle$ is prime and thus radical. It follows by the Nullstenlastz, that the ideal of functions which vanish on $V(g)$ is precisely $\langle g\rangle$. I claim that the only functions in $R$ are of the the form $f/g^k$ for $f\in k[x_1,\dots, x_k]$, and $k\geq 0$. Suppose that $p/h\in R$, then by definition $h(x)\neq 0$ for all $x\in U_g$, hence we have that $V(h)$ is either a subset of $V(g)$ (i.e. vanishes on a smaller closed set) or equal to $V(g)$.
Suppose that $V(h)\subset V(g)$, then we have that $\sqrt{\langle g\rangle }=\langle g\rangle \subset \sqrt{\langle h\rangle}$. Note that this implies that $g\in \sqrt{\langle h\rangle}$, hence $g^m=q\cdot h$ for some $q,m$. However, $g$ is irreducible, so $q$ and $h$ must be equal to some power of $g$, hence $h$ is of the form $g^k$ for some $k$.
If $V(h)=V(g)$ then we are done again as this implies $V(h)\subset V(g)$.
It follows that every element of $R$ is of the form $p/f^k$, so this object will clearly fulfill the universal property of localization at $g$ and thus be naturally isomorphic to $k[x_1,\dots, x_n]_g$.
Edit:
I am not entirely sure you need irreducibility...at least when working with the modern affine schemes instead of affine algebraic varities you have that $V(h)\subset V(g)$ so that $U_g\subset U_h$, then $h$ is invertible in $A_g$ anyways...
Supposing that $V(h)\subset V(g)$ we have that $g^m=q\cdot h$, so $q/g^m$ is an inverse for $h$ in $R$. It follows that $f/h$ can be written as $f\cdot q/g^m$ every element is still of this form.
As an example, if you localize $\mathbb k[x,y]$ at $xy$ this should still contain inverses for $x$ and $y$.
